# Interactive Brokers API issue with adding the ActiveX Control

Tags: c#, api, controls, activex, interactive

Every time I try to add the Interactive Brokers API control on my computer it gives me an error that sais....

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

I have been looking for an answer and trying different things for a week now and I can not seem to figure it out. I tried it on my laptop and it worked. I thought it was my windows or my visual studio so i re-installed everything on my PC. I'm not running a Windows 7 Professional x64 with Visual Studio 2013 with the newest update. At this point I have no idea what to try to make it work. Does anybody know what is this error.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry-very late for an answer to this but in case someone else comes across it. There are a number of reasons why Visual Studio might not be able to add the control to your application. For 64-bit windows, one of the main issues is that the ActiveX control (tws.ocx) is not registered properly when the API is installed. I have a web page dedicated to installing IB API on Windows and I list out many of the issues that can happen when working with the ActiveX control on 64-bit windows: http://holowczak.com/ib-install/

Answer (score 0):

I just posted a very simple tutorial on my website that starts at the very beginning and walks you through getting the API to work with interactive brokers using Visual Studio and C# : [Get Real-Time Stock data from Interactive Brokers API](http://www.jarloo.com/get-real-time-stock-data-using-the-interactive-brokers-api/)

If that doesn't help I would consider:

1. Turn off Windows Firewall and give it a try.
2. Ensure you have Traders Workstation setup to allow incomming connections for ActiveX/.NET.
3. Ensure Traders Workstation works on your machine. Try downloading it from IB and launching it. If it works, then the problem is on the .NET or connection from .NET to TWS which is Java.

Also when you say "Interactive Brokers Control" do you mean the API package that you can download? If so to build it into your program all you need is the .DLL file as shown in the tutorial link I posted above.